# Does a definition for delta sequences in the multidimensional case exist?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

does anybody know a good book on multidimensional delta sequences?

Comment: In harmonic analysis, "delta sequence" is synonymous to "approximation of the identity", for which you can enjoy
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function.

Vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest that you look at the *Annals of Statistics* paper "[Estimation of a Multivariate Density Function Using Delta Sequences](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2240793)," see if that paper's definition of a multivariate *delta sequence* matches what you have in mind by your phrase "multidimensional delta sequence," and if so, work forward in time
through the 17 more recent papers and books that Google Scholar lists as citing this early paper.
Finally, you might consider posting a more detailed version of your question to
https://stats.stackexchange.com/.